# What is the origin of the Krabby Patty Recipe

Tags: spongebob-squarepants

What is the origin of the Krabby Patty Recipe? Did Mr Krabs invent it? Did Spongebob have any hand in it?

Comment: Krabby patty, you mean?

Comment: @Catija ah yes, not crappy paddy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In "Friend or Foe" (season 5, ep 1) it's revealed in flashback that Mr. Krabs (by accident) creates the recipe as a child (after arguing with Plankton, who was up until that point his friend); a bunch of stuff falls into the batter after they argue and Plankton storms out.

Comment: Was it not also insinuated at one point that the secret ingredient was Mr. Krabs sweat? Would make total sense lore wise because he's a cheapskate and the Krabby Patty would literally taste like crab.